# Sim-Toolkit is missing from app drawer

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, art

I am running Android 4.4.2 (KitKat) on an [Nexus 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_4).

A day before I changed from [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) to [ART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime), and after the restart, I noticed that the Sim Toolkit is missing!

How do I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

It may well just have changed name; check through all your apps. Happened to me a couple of times, so I assume it's just a carrier thing.